# Delta Load on BSEG table into AZure using SAP table conenctor

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, abap, sap-erp

We are using SAP ABAP oracle environment.I'm trying to implement Change Data capture for the SAP BSEG table in Azure datafactory using SAP table connector. In SAP table connector, I don't see an option to pass any join conditions. Based on what fields we can capture the CDC on BSEG table.

Comment: Do you see an option to join for the other tables? If yes, then the reason is probably that `BSEG` is a special kind of table in the database. Why did you tag your question with `abap` as it seems to be Azure?

Comment: Create a view in SAP directly, that'll get you by.

Answer (score 0):

BSEG is a cluster table.
It dates back to R2 days on Mainframes.
See Se11 BSEG --> Menu option Database Object --> Database utility.
Run Check.
It will most likely say NOT ON DATABASE.

If you want to access the data via views see one of the numerous index tables.
**BSxx**   description  **Accounting: Secondary Index for xxxxx**

These so called Index tables are separate tables that behave like indexes
on bseg but arent true indexes as cluster tables can not have indexes.

The index tables  are real tables you can access with joins/views.
The document number can be used read BSEG later should that still be necessary.
You may find FI_DOCUMENT_READ and BKPF useful too.

In theory the Index tables should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SAP Table connector help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory):

> Currently SAP Table connector **only supports one single table** with the default function module. To get the joined data of multiple tables, you can leverage the customRfcReadTableFunctionModule property in the SAP Table connector following steps below
> ...

So no, table joins are not supported by default, you need to write in SAP backend a custom FM with the predefined interface. The interface to do is described in the help.

Comment: As Im new to SAP, I'm trying to fetch historical load of BSEG using Azure. Which column could be used to fetch the historical data and how this can be acheived?

Comment: Please ask a new question about this, this is totally unrelated to what you are asking in this one

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure Data factory to Azure Data Explorer doing big tables like BSEG can be done with a work around.

Although BSEG is a cluster of tables in SAP, from the SAP Connector point of view it is a table with rows and columns which can be partitioned.

Here is an example for MSEG which is similar.

[MSEG_Partitioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7WXD.png)

Kind Regards
Gauchet